# GreaseMonkey onclick binding

Tags: greasemonkey

When I write a GreaseMonkey script, if I create a div and set onclick to alert it works:

`var btn = document.createElement('div');
btn.setAttribute('onclick',"alert('clicked!');");`

However, if I ask it to do something else that was defined earlier then it fails:

`function graphIt() {...};
var btn = document.createElement('div');
btn.setAttribute('onclick',"graphIt();");`

Is there any way I can bind a function to the onclick event of a div?

Comment: PS. The function I want to call, calls some other functions as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your problem is that since you're seting the attribute to a string, it's evaluating the string in the context of the page itself, which doesn't have a `graphIt` function.

You should call the [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) method, like this:

```
function graphIt() {...}; var btn = document.createElement('div'); 
btn.addEventListener("click", graphIt, false);
```

Comment: Does this still work? I've tried and the button gets automatically clicked when the page loads...

Comment: @geekscrap: You probably called the function instead of passing it.

Comment: Ok, yes that is correct! Anything you can point me to that explains why this happens? TIA

Comment: @geekscrap: It's a function.  When you call it, it runs.