# Simple script with onclick event works fine in Chrome but fails in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, onclick, greasemonkey

I try to create an userscript using jQuery and JavaScript, but I am having a strange problem. I would like to add a onclick event to an image. It runs fine when I use Chrome (with TamperMonkey), but nothing happens when I click if using Firefox (with GreaseMonkey). However, the script is very basic. Assuming you have previously loaded jQuery and colorbox, here is what it is:

```
ok = "It works."

my_table = "<img onclick='alert(ok);' src='http://i.imgur.com/KrcyfFq.png' />";

$.colorbox({html:my_table,width:'33%',height:'33%'});
```

Uppercase the 'c' does not change anything. I also tried adding a javascript method attribute to a tag  but it does not work neither.

I really do not see why it would work in Chrome but not in Firefox. Could someone help me please?

Comment: Have you looked into JS console? What do you see there?

Comment: "ReferenceError: ok is not defined"
It makes sense...

Comment: alert(ok); means alerting a variable named ok. If you want to write the string "ok", you must use alert("ok"); ... ok? :)

Comment: Of course, I understand. The best way to solve this is : my_table = "<img onclick=\"alert('" + ok + "');\" src=\"http://i.imgur.com/KrcyfFq.png\" />"; It works fine.

Comment: There is no way this works in Tampermonkey.  You must have used different scripts or been messing about in the console.

Comment: possible duplicate of [GreaseMonkey onclick binding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718334/greasemonkey-onclick-binding)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it this way :

```
ok = "It works."

my_table = "<img class='clickableImg' src='http://i.imgur.com/KrcyfFq.png' />";

$.colorbox({html:my_table,width:'33%',height:'33%'});

$('.clickableImg').on('click', function(){
alert(ok);
});
```

Comment: Already tried, and it works fine. But I would like to know why the other method did not work.

In addition, it complicates my job a little easier because in my entire script, I add more images after using a loop, and each image must have its own onClick event. But I'll do that with a variable id in fact, it is not dumber, thank you.

Comment: If you need to pass custom data, different for each element, you can use data- attribute.
i think it's better than onclick.